# Improving performance for my code with Pandas dataframe (column operation )

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I am learning Pandas dataframe and a question related to performance optimization. As I am slow and new, it appears that my code is not written correctly and performing poorly even though the output is correct.

Problem: I have bit patterns of 0 and 1. I have to find the stride of 1 (count of contiguos 1 for my analysis). My data frame is 200,000 columns x 200 rows. It is very slow right now and looking for a better way to do the complete solution or the 'for loop' replacement with vector operation for all columns. Example:

```
Input:  1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1 
Output: 4,4,4,4,0,0,2,2,0,0,3,3,3 (1 is replaced with the stride for 1)
```

I have abstracted a sample code for review. I would appreciate if someone can help a noob.

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
# Small sample
AA = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
AB = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
AC = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
AD = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
AE = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"A0": AA, "A1": AB, "A2": AB, "A3": AB, "A4": AB, "A5": AC, "A6": AD, "A7": AE, "A8": AE, "A9": AE})
# End of Debug Data Frame

df2=pd.DataFrame() # initialize to empty

print("Starting")
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
df1=pd.DataFrame(df != df.shift()).cumsum() # Operation-1: detects edges and increments at edge

print("Processing columns. Time=", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
    
for c in df1.columns:
    df2[c] = df1.groupby(c)[c].transform('count') * df[c] # This takes maximum time as I am counting column by column

print("Done Processing columns. Time=", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

For my dataframe (200,000 columns x 200 rows), 'for loop' is taking 700 sec

```
Starting
Processing columns. Time= 0.9377922620624304
Done Processing columns. Time= 701.7339988127351
Done generating data. Time= 702.0729111488909
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative, on sample dataframe, not sure the difference in speed is significant but should be on a bigger one. The idea is to use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) along the rows (for each column at once), use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) with original df as Boolean to replace by `pd.NA` the values in the cumsumed df where df is 1. Then you need to play with some `bfill`, `ffill` and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) to get the expected result.

```
df_ = df.cumsum().mask(df.astype(bool)) # Removing pd.NaT helped
df2 = (df_.bfill() - df_.ffill().fillna(0)).fillna(0)

print(df2)
    A0  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9
0    1   0   0   0   0   2   0  10  10  10
1    0   8   8   8   8   2   1  10  10  10
2    0   8   8   8   8   0   0  10  10  10
3    2   8   8   8   8   2   1  10  10  10
4    2   8   8   8   8   2   0  10  10  10
5    0   8   8   8   8   0   1  10  10  10
6    0   8   8   8   8   0   0  10  10  10
7    0   8   8   8   8   0   1  10  10  10
8    1   8   8   8   8   1   0  10  10  10
9    0   0   0   0   0   0   1  10  10  10
10   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
11   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
12   5   5   5   5   5   5   0   0   0   0
13   5   5   5   5   5   5   1   0   0   0
14   5   5   5   5   5   5   0   0   0   0
15   5   5   5   5   5   5   1   0   0   0
16   5   5   5   5   5   5   0   0   0   0
17   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
18   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response. It tested out well on the smaller test sequences. As I moved to my large dataset, it never finishes even after over an hour. I broke the solution you provided in steps for debugging,  and 'df_.ffill().fillna(0)' is taking forever. Any suggestions or alternatives?

Comment: @Dsrivast I'm a bit surprised that just this part is so long! From what I know, the only thing I don't use usually is `pd.NA` in the previous line. so try to just do `df_ = df.cumsum().mask(df.astype(bool))` and see if you still have a problem of efficiency. then you might need to cast to integer the final result

Comment: @Ben-T That did the trick and i am seeing 12x performance improvement. Thanks so much and appreciate the help.

Comment: Someone downgraded my question. I spent a lot of time doing research and following guidelines. Please help me understand how I can improve my questions. As I am learning, I would like to continue asking without too much pressure of getting downgraded.

Comment: @Dsrivast glad to know that wihtout pd.NA it works better, I will dig into this performance issue with pd.NA.

Comment: @Dsrivast so to me, the only thing that could lead to a downvote is because strictly speaking, stackoverflow is for code that does not work with an error while your code is working and you seek for optimization, hence it would be more suitable for the site code review exchange. But honestly, your question state your problem clearly, you give a toy sample and a way to reproduce the expected output. I have seen question less good without any downvote, so I would not be worried to much about it (I know it s*** though). I can do minor correction if you want, but I`m not the best to write question

Comment: @Ben-T thanks for your encouraging response. Yes, would appreciate if you can edit my question to make it useful for the community. FYI, the code is super fast and useful. There is a bug if all the bits are '1. I didn't find an elegant solution after a number of trials. My workaround is to add a row with all '0 which solves the problem as the column fins a transition. Sorry for delay as I got pulled into an urgent issue.